# How to make EMF remove generated code for removed attributes

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

After removing an attribute from an ecore model, I re-generate the code, but the methods from the removed attributes remains in the generated code. Is there an automatic way to remove this code?

Edit - the code is removed from the interface, but not from the implementation. I would like to remove it from the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not always work, the only way I know is to delete the impl classes and re-generate the code based on the new ecore model.

Answer (score 1):

If your implementation classes have the @generated tag in the javadoc of the attributes, they should be removed too.